# .net MVC 2 controller inheritance

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have i little problem with inheritance of my controllers for example :

```
public class AController: Controller {
 public ActionResult Index(long id)
        {
            return Index(id, isComposite);
        }
}
public class BController : AController {


}
```

when i click on ../B/Index/12 i get following exception : the view 'Index' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched: ~/Views/B/Index.aspx 
I can copy Index.aspx into "Shared" map but may be there is other workaround ? 
Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in `~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx` but in ASP.NET MVC it is better to avoid such type of controller inheritance.

Comment: Why? If i have some generic functionality ?

Comment: @user872761, in ASP.NET MVC there are other ways of implementing generic functionality: action filters, model binders, repositories, ... depending of course on the common functionality you are willing to implement.